# Error: Unable to detect column types for pre-aggregation on empty values in readOnly mode [CubeJs]

Tags: cube.js

1. Using mongo Bi connector via Atlas as source database
2. Using mysql for pre-aggregation

Comment: ```Error: User: Single quoted string is expected but Value(Number(\"0\", false)) found``` while using cube store

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to use pre-aggregations if the source data is stored in MongoDB. Please see this GitHub issue for details: https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/issues/2858

If you'd like to use pre-aggregations for performance, syncing data from MongoDB into another data store is the only viable option.

Comment: Which all databases would you recommend for source data, if one want to use pre-aggregation with that?

Comment: How soon can we expect pre-aggregation support for MongoDB with external database?

Comment: Pretty much anything from this list of supported databases (except for MongoDB): https://cube.dev/docs/connecting-to-the-database. MySQL, Postgres, BigQuery, Redshift, Snowflake, etc. — all of them will work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide a time estimate for the pre-aggregations support with regard to MongoDB.